# How to dynamically Update/Edit/Delete existing record within a list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

new to rails and could use some help figuring out how to allow users to update records in a list without having to leave the page.

Specifically, I have two forms on a page where users enter their children's info.

One form is for the user to add a NEW child's info to create a list of children below.
The list of children displays the user's previously entered children info.
However, within the child list I would like to allow users to both delete and edit an individual child's record.

My DELETE function is working fine, it's the UPDATE functionality I am having trouble with...

Here's the children#update controller:

```
def update
  raise
  @user = current_user
  @child = Child.find(params[:id])
  if @child.update_attributes(child_params)
    flash[:notice] = "Child info was updated."
  else
    flash[:error] = "Sorry.  Something went wrong, please try again."
  end
  respond_with(@child) do |f|
    f.html { redirect_to new_child_path }
  end
end
```

Here's the childlist form partial view:

```
<form role="form">
  <% i = 1 %>
  <% @user.children.each do |child| %>
  <div class="col-md-12 form-align list-line">
    <div class="col-md-10 form-align">
      <%= label_tag child, "Child #{i}:" %>
      <% i += 1 %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= form_for(child, method: :put) do |f| %>
    <div class="col-md-12 form-align">
      <div class='col-md-4 form-align'>
        <%= f.label :first_name, class: 'sr-only' %>
        <%= f.text_field :first_name, value: child.first_name, class: 'form-control form-control-align'  %>
      </div>
      <div class='col-md-4 form-align'>
        <%= f.label :middle_name, class: "sr-only" %>
        <%= f.text_field :middle_name, value: child.middle_name, class: 'form-control form-control-align'  %>
      </div>
      <div class='col-md-4 form-align'>
        <%= f.label :last_name, class: "sr-only" %>
        <%= f.text_field :last_name, value: child.last_name, class: 'form-control form-control-align'  %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 form-align">
      <div class="col-md-4 form-group form-inline form-align">
        <%= f.label :birth_date, "D.O.B." %>
        <%= f.date_field  :birth_date, value: child.birth_date,  class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 form-group form-inline form-align">
        <%= f.label :deceased, "Deceased?" %>
        <%= f.select :deceased, value: child.deceased?,  class: 'form-control form-control-align' %>
      </div>
      <%= f.submit "Update" %>
      <%= link_to '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove red"></i>'.html_safe, child,  method: :delete %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
</form>
```

...and the child model: simply belongs_to :user / user model has_many :children

...and routes: resources :children

I think I need some options passed through my form_for, but unable to find what those need to be...

Comment: You should consider deleting this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a gem like [Best in Place](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) to allow for in-place editing on certain fields in the list.

If you don't want in-place editing then utilize a modal view that contains the edit form.

Comment: Another option could be [X-Editable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/) for in-place editing.

Comment: Thanks Kyle!  Will check those out!